# Swift - how can you build a web based app?

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a web based iOS app.
Simply say, my system is like below.

1. A user input his name on the app
2. the app POST it to "destination.php"
3. "destination.php" stores the received POST to a DB

On the app side, Swift code will be like below.

```
let strData = parameter.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let url = NSURL(string:"http://example.com/destination.php")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.HTTPBody = strData
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()){(res, data, err) in
    //do something
}
```

I already confirmed that it works well, but from a security point of view, I'm not comfortable with this, because there are no security authorization between the app and "destination.php". In other words, if someone evil finds the URL of "destination.php", he can easily mess up the system with some scripts (posting tons of data to the php, for example).

Is there any good ways to make this kind of connection secure?

Comment: I would say that this isn't a question about Swift or iOS. What you're asking about is how to securely use HTTP, and that's another topic entirely.

Comment: Use `NSURLSession`. Much better API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up Basic authentication on your server and use something like this to build your request.

```
func request(url: NSURL) -> NSURLRequest {
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.setValue(self.authorisation(), forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    return request
}

func authorisation() -> String {
    let string = "stuff".stringByAppendingFormat(":%@", "password")
    let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)
    let encodedString = data?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding76CharacterLineLength)
    let returnValue = "Basic".stringByAppendingFormat(" %@", encodedString!)
    return returnValue
}
```

Comment: Oh, that's the way. Thank you! I have been trying to implement the way, but haven't been success. Do you have any good solutions to know if my authentication is successfully done or not? (i.e. showing error message)

Comment: If your happy @stackgk then please mark this answer as correct.